# How to enable combination of orExpression and andExpression rule in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to parse the following with antlr4

```
isSet(foo) or isSet(bar) and isSet(test)
```

Actually i can see in the parse tree that only the first or is recognized, I can add multiple or's and the parse tree grows, but an additional and will not be recognized. How can I define this in the grammar?

This my current grammar file:

```
        grammar Expr;
        
        prog: (stat)+;
        stat: (command | orExpression | andExpression | notExpression)+;
        orExpression: command ( OR command | XOR command)*;
        andExpression:command ( AND command)*;
        notExpression:NOT command;
        command:IS_SET LPAREN parameter RPAREN
                | IS_EMPTY LPAREN parameter RPAREN;
        parameter: ID;
        
        
        LPAREN : '(';
        RPAREN : ')';
        LBRACE : '{';
        RBRACE : '}';
        LBRACK : '[';
        RBRACK : ']';
        SEMI : ';';
        COMMA : ',';
        DOT : '.';
        ASSIGN : '=';
        GT : '>';
        LT : '<';
        BANG : '!';
        TILDE : '~';
        QUESTION : '?';
        COLON : ':';
        EQUAL : '==';
        LE : '<=';
        GE : '>=';
        NOTEQUAL : '!=';
        AND : 'and';
        OR : 'or';
        XOR :'xor';
        NOT :'not'  ;
        INC : '++';
        DEC : '--';
        ADD : '+';
        SUB : '-';
        MUL : '*';
        DIV : '/';
        
        INT: [0-9]+;
        NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n';
        IS_SET:'isSet';
        IS_EMPTY:'isEmpty';
        WS: [\t]+ -> skip;
        ID
            :   JavaLetter JavaLetterOrDigit*
            ;
        
        fragment
        JavaLetter
            :   [a-zA-Z$_] // these are the "java letters" below 0xFF
            |   // covers all characters above 0xFF which are not a surrogate
                ~[\u0000-\u00FF\uD800-\uDBFF]
                {Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(_input.LA(-1))}?
            |   // covers UTF-16 surrogate pairs encodings for U+10000 to U+10FFFF
                [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF]
                {Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(Character.toCodePoint((char)_input.LA(-2), (char)_input.LA(-1)))}?
            ;
        
        fragment
        JavaLetterOrDigit
            :   [a-zA-Z0-9$_] // these are the "java letters or digits" below 0xFF
            |   // covers all characters above 0xFF which are not a surrogate
                ~[\u0000-\u00FF\uD800-\uDBFF]
                {Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(_input.LA(-1))}?
            |   // covers UTF-16 surrogate pairs encodings for U+10000 to U+10FFFF
                [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF]
                {Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(Character.toCodePoint((char)_input.LA(-2), (char)_input.LA(-1)))}?
            ;
```

Here you can see the parse tree, with the missing andExpression

[image]

Comment: Show your lexer output.  I think it'll help you.  Run grun in -tokens mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first part is parsed because the rule `prog: (stat)+;` is only told to parse at least 1 `stat`, which it does. If you want the parser to process all tokens, "anchor" your start rule with the `EOF` token:

```
prog : stat+ EOF;
```

And now your input `isSet(foo) or isSet(bar) and isSet(test)` will produce an error message. The first part, `isSet(foo) or isSet(bar)`, is still recognised as a `orExpression`, but the last part `and isSet(test)` cannot be matched. The general idea is to do something like this:

```
prog          : stat+ EOF;
stat          : orExpression+;
orExpression  : andExpression ( OR andExpression | XOR andExpression)*;
andExpression : notExpression ( AND notExpression)*;
notExpression : NOT? command;
command       : IS_SET LPAREN parameter RPAREN
              | IS_EMPTY LPAREN parameter RPAREN;
parameter     : ID;
```

But ANTLR4 supports direct left recursive rules, so you could also write the rules above like this:

```
prog: expr+ EOF;

expr
 : NOT expr                  #NotExpr
 | expr AND expr             #AndExpr
 | expr (OR | XOR) expr      #OrExpr
 | IS_SET LPAREN expr RPAREN #CommandExpr
 | ID                        #IdExpr
 ;
```

which is, IMO, much nicer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I am reading the antlr4 reference book there is it described that direct left recursive rules are supported. With your second solution I see that it is working, great. The precedence is regulated by the order of the rules? And is there a way to support parenthesis in my rule, so that it is possible to group some rules with parenthesis.

Comment: "The precedence is regulated by the order of the rules?", correct, `AndExpr` has a higher precedence than `OrExpr`

Comment: "And is there a way to support parenthesis in my rule, so that it is possible to group some rules with parenthesis" from your new question on SO, I see you already figured that out :)

Comment: Yes, but really thanks for the help. Maybe there will be another question concerning to traverse the parse tree :-)